# Automatically add client USB drive to VMWare Linux virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, usb

I have this problem with adding USB devices to VMWare ESX host Linux VM in a client-level.
I know how to add device to VM by connecting USB to host or using client device by using VSphere.

But how can I automate that without touching the ESX management consoles? Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you looked at Power CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need the USB for, I'd look into a USB virtualization appliance, they are a network attached box that you connect your USB stuff to, and then you just install a small program on the VM that creates a virtual USB port. That way the USB device "moves" with the VM when it gets moved between hosts.